# jQuery Ajax .post() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     console.log("Document ready...");

     $.post("...file.asmx/HelloWorld", function(data) {

          console.log("Post Successful");               
     });            
});
```

I get the following console output:

```
[10:01:44.528] Document ready...
[10:01:44.601] POST ..file.asmx/HelloWorld [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 103ms]
```

My question is why is the second log call not executing? It seems like the post was successful and the function should execute. I'm using firefox.

Also:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
      console.log( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
      console.log(exception);
});
```

When I try and log the exception I get a blank line in my console.

Comment: Depending on what type of data is returned from the service, you might want to pass a 4th parameter to `$.post()` that says what the format of the response is (JSON, HTML, text, etc. ...). If you don't, jQuery guesses on how to parse the response based on its `Content-Type` header. Also, I think in recent versions of jQuery, an empty response is considered invalid JSON, whereas it use to be okay

Answer (score 2):

A `200 OK` response does not guarantee a successful AJAX call.

Cross-origin Resource Sharing rules might prohibit access to the resource, or the content returned might be unparsable.

Add an error callback and look to see if that's called, and if so, with what arguments.

Since `$.post` doesn't directly support an error callback, you can use "deferred" syntax:

```
$.post(...).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // log here
});
```

Comment: @user1737909 just because the HTTP status is OK it doesn't guarantee that the download was parsed correctly.  Or it might have failed CORS security checks.

Comment: When I try and log errorThrown nothing shows up, but the function is being called.